# Native language problem in text() and html in jQuery

Tags: jquery

There is native language problem text() and html in jQuery :

```
$("li p span").html("");
$("li.checked p span").html('çşğü : ' + myVar);
```

The output is not similar to html() and look like unknown characters.

Im not using any serverside language and meta charset is `charset=utf-8`.
How can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the JavaScript in the same file as the HTML?

Comment: @James Hall; javascript has included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file needs to be UTF-8 encoded as well. Check the encoding in whatever program you use to edit the file.

If the file has a UTF-8 "content-type" meta tag at the top, and its contents are UTF-8 encoded, and the server is not sending a header saying otherwise, it should work.